# How can I restart the text to speech feature?

Tags: text-to-speech

I use the text to speech feature a lot. Sometimes, after I put the macbook to sleep and come back to it the feature no longer works. I would have to shutdown/restart the computer in order for the feature to work. Is there are a way to restart/enable text to speech without restarting the computer?

Comment: Try running Activity Monitor, search for the Process Name `coreaudiod`, and force quit it by clicking the X icon and selecting Force Quit. Speech Synthesis uses the `coreaudiod`daemon process for its [audio output](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SpeechSynthesisProgrammingGuide/SpeechOverview/SpeechOverview.html):

Comment: @IconDaemon that did it. The only problem now is that the keyboardshortcut is not working

Comment: Which keyboard shortcut? Be specific.

Comment: @IconDaemon Sorry, I have a shortcut set for text-to-speach (option + esc), not that does not work.

Comment: Ah. This is set in the `System Preferences > Accessibility > Speech` sidebar. Is the checkbox checked in this setting?

Comment: @IconDaemon Yes it is checked, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 5):

have you tried entering these two commands in terminal?

```
killall com.apple.speech.speechsynthesisd
killall SpeechSynthesisServer
```

You can do that in activity monitor, I just like terminal better.
Then wait a bit and try the shortcut again. 
If that doesn't work, try to change your shortcut to something else and then change it back.
Also, maybe corrupted plist file?

Comment: I have to kill coreaudio every once in awhile and it takes down speech too. This fixes it. Thanks!